# How do I disable Zoom and Scroll in Web Browser control for a WP8 app?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, wptoolkit

I'm developing an App for WP8 using Visual Studio 2013. I used the WPToolkit to integrate the WebBrowser control.

I'm displaying static information in my WebBrowser control with changes just to the text using the following function.

```
Private Function CreateHtmlDocument() As String

    Dim strHtmlDoc As String = ""

    strHtmlDoc = "<html>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<head>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no';>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "</head>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<style type='text/css'>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "body{ -ms-touch-action: none !important; -ms-content-zooming:none; -ms-scroll-limit-y-max :auto;}"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "</style>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<body>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<span style='color:#bf2e1a'><b><font face='Times New Roman' size='3'>" & clsGlobalVariables.branch & "</font></b></span>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<br> <span style='color:#c1481a'><font face='Times New Roman' size='2'>" & clsGlobalVariables.company_name & "<br> (Legal Name : " & clsGlobalVariables.legal_name & ")</font></span>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<br> <span style='color:#878270'><p align='left'><font face='Arial' size='2'>" & clsGlobalVariables.address & "</font></p> </span>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<span style='color:#878270'><font face='Arial' size='2'>Tel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</span> <span style='color:blue'>" & clsGlobalVariables.telephone & "</font></span>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<br> <span style='color:#878270'><font face='Arial' size='2'>Fax &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</span> <span style='color:blue'>" & clsGlobalVariables.fax & "</font></span>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<br> <span style='color:#878270'><font face='Arial' size='2'>Email&nbsp;:</span> <span style='color:blue'>" & clsGlobalVariables.email & "</font></span>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<br>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "<br>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "</body>"
    strHtmlDoc = strHtmlDoc & "</html>"


    Return strHtmlDoc

End Function
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to disable Pinch Zoom. Thankfully, double-tap zoom doesn't work. Also, the scroll is bugged in that it scrolls beyond my data and shows blank space in my control.

Some Image Links(Still don't have 10 Rep) -

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eifhn.jpg      - How it looks normally.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0panl.jpg      - It zooms too much.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/znf5y.jpg      - It scrolls way below the text.
```

I already tried http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html . It doesn't work for WP8.

My XAML -

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" Margin="10,274,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" IsScriptEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="OrangeRed" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a sealed class, so if you really want to achieved this, then you would need to transverse the VisualTree to get to the correct container.

Just a small workaround then:  (Disabled Zoom, but enable scrolling)

Hardcoded Values

```XAML
<ScrollViewer>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="my_wb" Height="1000" IsHitTestVisible="False"></phone:WebBrowser>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you know how to pass JS values back to calling Application you can size the WebBrowser perfectly.

```XAML
<ScrollViewer>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="my_wb" Height="{Binding HeightOfRenderHTMLpage}" IsHitTestVisible="False"></phone:WebBrowser>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What about cases where you NEED to scroll to view the entire data?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/K98VY.jpg

Comment: Then you need to modify your question, it says "How I disable Zoom and Scroll"

Comment: My bad. Can you answer the question anyway? I'll take care as to question accuracy in the future.

Comment: It's a sealed class, so you would have to muck around in the VisualTree to do what you want.  But I will post a simpler workaround since I don't know how proficient you're as a coder.  You can set a Hard value for the height or you employ some JS Binding to get the exact height of the page.  I will modify my solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I increased my Grid Size and changed my buttons to icons to make it work with your previous solution. But I'll check this out. Again, thanks a lot.

Btw, can you give me some links to learn about VisualTree?

Comment: :) sure.  It all starts here.  It's basically browsing through a directory tree.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue (i think) last month, here's my solution (in C#).

Set IsHitTestVisible to false for disabling all interaction with user and enable scripts with IsScriptEnabled to true

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition
              Height="auto" />
          <RowDefinition
              Height="auto" />
          <RowDefinition
              Height="auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock
          Grid.Row="0"
          x:Name="Subject" />
      <TextBlock
          Grid.Row="1"
          x:Name="Date" />
      <phone:WebBrowser
          Grid.Row="2"
          ScriptNotify="browser_ScriptNotify"
          x:Name="browser"
          IsHitTestVisible="False"
          IsScriptEnabled="True" />
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Before you set HTML to to browser, inject javascript with bodyheight callback

**C#**

```
// preparing HTML page with some viewport settings and JS callback to c#
private string PrepareHtml(string body)
{
    return @"<!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
                <head>
                    <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=432, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    " + body + @"

                    <script type=""text/javascript"">

                        window.external.notify(document.body.clientHeight.toString());

                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>";
}
```

when getting notified of clients height, set browsers height

**C#**

```
void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    int o;
    if (int.TryParse(e.Value, out o))
    {
        browser.Height = o;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps